# Generalize Gauss-Bonnet Formula to non-simple closed curves

Tags: differential-geometry

According to the Classical Gauss-Bonnet Formula, I think it should can be generalized to non-simple closed curves in the following sense:

For a domain $\Omega$ enclosed by an non-simple closed curve $\gamma$ on a Surface, we have $$\int_{\gamma}k_gds+\int_{\Omega} KwdA+\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=2\pi\text{ind}(\gamma)$$
where $w(p)$ is the winding number of the curve with respect to $p$, $k_g,K,\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$, the Gauss Curvature of the Surface, the exterior angle at the corners.

Does anyone have ever know this type of formula? Thank you very much if you can give any guides.

***Many thanks if you can give any reference!***
(I know about the Classical Gauss-Bonnet Formula and I want to get a reference (books, papers or any other materials) about this version.)

Comment: That's a version of Hopf's theorem on winding numbers, I believe.

Comment: What do you mean my *non-simple closed curve*? Do you mean an *immersed* closed curve?

Comment: The right hand side is $2\pi\chi(\Omega)$. This is freshmen differential geometry, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev, you are right, "it is freshmen differential geometry", but you wrong about right hand side.

Comment: You aren't really talking about an extension of the Gauss-Bonnet Formula, more just one of the standard ways of stating it.  Isn't it stated essentially the above way in Milman-Parker, for instance?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Oops, sorry, haven't noticed the $w$. But then I don't understand what $w$ means if the surface is not simply connected.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: Yes, for non-simple closed curve, I means an immersed closed curve, it can have intersections and corners.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev: Thanks! I assume the curve is non-simple closed, means an immersed closed curve, it can have self-intersections and corners. For $w(p)$, I means the winding number of the curve with respect to the point $p$, and you can define this from a topological viewpoint. I also think its "freshmen differential geometry", but could you give me any reference? Thanks very much!

Comment: @RyanBudney: Yes, I think so. But I haven't find this version in Milman-Parker. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The surface has to be orientable. The curve is a closed piecewise immersion, with corners at countably many points.
The index is the rotation index (the winding number of the velocity $\gamma'$, where at each jump point one has to add the jump angle). One can prove this by decomposing $\Omega$ into (at most countably many) parts which are bounded by simple closed curves (like the two interiors of the figure eight, for example) and use Gauss-Bonnet for each of these parts and some cancellation of angles at the self-intersection points of the curve. Try to prove it first for the figure eight, then for a circle which is traversed $k$-times, then introduce corners, then the general case.

For the rotation index see also the Whitney-Graustein theorem, in a generalized version in 
2.9 and 2.10 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/curves.pdf).

Comment: Thanks very much! Could you give me any reference where I can find this version of Gauss-Bonnet Formula?